# How to tell if a multivariable limit really exists?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Hi i'm having this doubt about this multivariable limit

$$ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{2x^2y}{x^4+y^2} $$

If I use these two paths like let $x = y^3$ and $y=x$ I get that the limit is going to be 0, however if I add this other path where $x=\sqrt y$ the limit is going to be 1, and that tells me the limit doesn't exist, but what if I just used the first ones? while doing the proof by definition shouldn't this be refuted? cause I don't know if i'm applying this the wrong way and ending up with a valid limit when I shouldn't, how do you guys know exactly which paths you can use to say that the limit doesn't exists? is there like a rule or something similar? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in multivariable functions you can say that a limit exist proving it by definition. You only use different paths to see if a limit doesn't exist (case that you get different values), or to find a candidate to be the limit and use it to proving that by definition.

You don't have a way to see exactly which paths you have to use. You can use the lines x=0, y=mx and then all depends on your creativity.

Sometimes can be useful to plot some level sets of the function, and analize if exist a trivial path which aproximates the point in a special way that can give a diferent value of the limit.

I hope it had been helpful.

Comment: Exactly, in this case i used the first two paths as i earlier mentioned I got 0, then by definition that's the value i used then I got to the point where the absolute value of the the function is < than Epsilon and I thought I proved it, but then I noticed afterwards because a friend told me if you used that path where $x = \sqrt y$ the limit doesn't exists cause is different as the other two paths I already used, but then again the main question is does the definition tells me if it really exists? even wolfram alpha says this limit is 0 however in leithold's 7th edition says it doesn't exists

Comment: Yes, limit by definition always work. Maybe you do something wrong when you try to proof it? I try to solve it and using the path x=sqrt(y) the limit goes to 1, but using the path y=mx goes to 0. So, the limit doesn't exist. Don't trust always on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Alright thanks so much yeah i'm gonna try and see what's the failure with the definition I tried

Comment: Excellent, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The statement that the limit exists means that for all neighborhoods $N_\varepsilon L$ there is a neighborhood $M_\delta (0,0)$ such that whenever $x \in M_\delta(0,0)$, it follows that $f(x) \in N_\varepsilon L$.

Thus, if you can find two paths that give different limits, the limit cannot exist since our condition about being in some $\delta$-neighborhood implying proximity to $L$ is not satisfied.

Consider the path $(x, x^2)$:
$$
\lim_{(x,x^2)\to(0,0)} \frac{2x^2x^2}{x^4+(x^2)^2} = \lim_{(x,x^2)\to(0,0)} \frac{2x^4}{2x^4} = 1.
$$

Consider the path $(x,0)$, that is, approaching along the $x$-axis:
$$
\lim_{(x,0)\to(0,0)} \frac{2x^2\cdot 0}{x^4+0} = \lim_{(x,0)\to(0,0)} 0 = 0.
$$

Hence, the limit does not exist. In general, if we evaluate the limit of a function $f$ along a certain path $p_1$ and determine the limit along this path is, say $L'$, then that is all we have determined. However, to say that *the limit* of the function is some particular value $L$ means that it is the value we achieve if we approach along *every* path. Thus, we have not shown *the limit* is anything until we have shown that the limiting value is the same for *all paths*.

Comment: I get that, however how do you prove that the limit doesn't exist by definition? i don't see what i did wrong while proving it was 0, and it is a wrong answer

Comment: @NeptaliD, I have updated my answer to address that question.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the general result on this:

**Lemma** For positive $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon$ The limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,o)} \frac{|x|^\alpha |y|^\beta}{(|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta)^\epsilon} = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
0 & \mbox{ if }  \frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+\frac{\beta}{\delta} >\epsilon \\
\mbox{DNE} & \mbox{ if }  \frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+\frac{\beta}{\delta} \leq \epsilon 
\end{array}\right.$$

**Proof:**

$$|x|^\alpha |y|^\beta= (|x|^\gamma)^{\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}}(|y|^\delta)^{\frac{\beta}{\delta}}\leq  (|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}}(|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta)^{\frac{\beta}{\delta}} \\
 \frac{|x|^\alpha |y|^\beta}{(|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta)^\epsilon} \leq (|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta)^{ \frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+\frac{\beta}{\delta} -\epsilon}$$

which proves the first part.

For the second, pick the curve paramatrised by $|x|^\gamma=|y|^\delta=t$ and calculate the limit along this curve.

---

In your problem, you need to decide if $\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}$ is $>$ or $\leq $ than 1.